# How to achieve volume slider effect like on vimeo in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript, slider, vimeo

The video player (aka moogaloop) on vimeo.com  has a neat visual effect for the audio volume slider. There are a number of sound bars that rise and fall when the mouse hovers over them. The volume level is shown by a blue filled area under the bars with pixel precision.

This puzzles me, how can the multiple masks (bars) be used to cover a single blue rectangle?

**Update**: [Masks in flash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS9388626D-B940-43f3-87BB-7C3159F5EDE4.html): "the mask item acts as a window that reveals the area of linked layers beneath it [...] A mask layer can contain only one mask item". How do I get multiple masks to clip over one layer?

Comment: Are you looking for transparency? You can achieve them using `alpha` property.

Comment: No, it's a bit more complicated. I think i found it - it's a clipping mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your moving/interactive bars inside **one movieclip** that is in a layer masking your blue box, and you're done!

Comment: Tried it - only the first bar creates a masking effect, the content under other bars stays invisible... Weird.

Comment: It worked the second time around - thanks! The solution was one mask layer with one movieclip of multiple animated bars. A layer below it with the fluctuating blue bar. Awesome and simple.